# Ruby on Rails changing sass variables from views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

I wanna change bootstrap sass variables from the views and I have tried internal css and it doesn't work any ideas:

```
<% if current_user.admin == true%>
    <!-- Change sass variables-->
 <% else %>
    <!-- use default sass variables -->
 <% end %>
```

Comment: SASS gets compiled to pure CSS for production, you cannot change the variables in runtime.

Comment: you cannot change sass variables on erb templates .. you can define different CSS classes to use in `if .. else` blocks

Comment: @sa77 I'm sorry I'm a little new to this so can you explain a little more or give me some sort of reference links

Comment: @J.Foe couldn't find link with related content .. added an answer. give that a try !

Answer (score 1):

SASS variables cannot be changed on erb templates. One way to do it is by defining different CSS classes with the help of SASS mixins for each of these `if .. else` cases. For example:

SASS rules:

```
$default-color: #666;
$admin-color: #333;


@mixin common-style($color) {
  color: $color;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.default-div {
  @include common-style($default-color)
}

.admin-div {
  @include common-style($admin-color)
}
```

Then, on your view file:

```
<% if current_user.admin == true%>
    <!-- use admin CSS -->
    <div class='admin-div'>
    </div>
 <% else %>
    <!-- use default CSS rules -->
    <div class='default-div'>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```